# im trying to dockerize a simple project i made and had some issues

Tags: javascript, reactjs, docker-compose

https://github.com/itay1989/PP.git

above is the git repo for my problem.
i tried dockerize an existing project i made and i encounter some issues with the server (api) connecting to the database (postgres). in the repo i cli the server container to get the ip and tried to route all buttons in the ./src/components... files to the server and it still dont function.

thats the warning i get . client still works but i have no functionality.
any help would be appreciated .

```
client_1    | Compiled with warnings.
client_1    |
client_1    | ./src/components/InputTodo.js
client_1    |   Line 10:13:  'response' is assigned a value but never used  no-unused-vars
client_1    |
client_1    | ./src/components/ListTodos.js
client_1    |   Line 12:13:  'deleteTodo' is assigned a value but never used  no-unused-vars
client_1    |
client_1    | ./src/components/EditTodo.js
client_1    |   Line 12:13:  'response' is assigned a value but never used  no-unused-vars
client_1    |
client_1    | Search for the keywords to learn more about each warning.
client_1    | To ignore, add // eslint-disable-next-line to the line before.
```

Comment: FYI: Those warnings you've added to the bottom of your post are just linter warnings about your code. They will have no effect on the dockerization process. I also just had a look at your repo, there are more complex issues regarding your project structure that aren't going to help you and will take more than a Stack Overflow answer to resolve.

Answer (score 0):

You should use different approach to access backend from frontend. For example, at https://github.com/itay1989/PP/blob/master/client/src/components/EditTodo.js#L13 :

```js
      const response = await fetch(
        `http://172.22.0.4:5000/todos/${todo.todo_id}`, // <- BAD!
        {
          method: "PUT",
          headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
          body: JSON.stringify(body)
        }
      );
```

This is wrong because containers IPs may change from one execution to another. And it will surely change from one environment to another.

#### Solution

CRA allows using [environmental variables](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/) from within your code:

```js
      const response = await fetch(
        `${process.env.REACT_APP_BACK_URL}/todos/${todo.todo_id}`, // <- GOOD!
        {
          method: "PUT",
          headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
          body: JSON.stringify(body)
        }
      );
```

And then, add it to your `docker-compose.yml`:

```yaml
  client:
    # ...
    environment:
      - CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true 
      - REACT_APP_BACK_URL=http://api:5000
```

Here, I am using the name defined in the `api` service, which will be defined in all the containers' `/etc/hosts`.

#### Note:

Analyzing full repo for errors, without full logs and testing env, forces us to install it on our machines. In next questions, please, consider debugging a bit more before asking and reduce it to the narrowest possible containing the error.

Here, I just look over the code a bit and spot one error (I didn't installed it). There might be more bugs.